# SQL HAVING BETWEEN a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, between, having

I am trying to retrieve the count of records between a certain date range that is specific to the users min date and max date in another table.

This is what I have so far, however it is excluding at least 13 records that I know of. Can you tell if there is an error in my logic?

Thanks in advance for any input you have!

```
SELECT   rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.user_id AS user_id,
         MIN(rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.LOCAL_USER_START_TIME) AS Min_Date,
         MAX(rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.LOCAL_USER_START_TIME) AS Max_Date,
         0 AS IVR_Calls,
         COUNT(*) AS Total_Calls
FROM     rtam.dbo.WFM_PROCESS_INSTANCE
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         rtam.dbo.WFM_PROCESS_type
         ON rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.PROCESS_TYPE_INDX = rtam.dbo.wfm_process_type.INDX
WHERE    rtam.dbo.wfm_process_type.DISPLAY_NAME = 'DTV Inbound2'
         AND EXISTS (SELECT   rtam.dbo.gnr_Tbl_72_type.CTRL_USER_ID,
                              CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), MIN(rtam.dbo.gnr_tbl_72_type.LOCAL_COL_113), 101) AS min_date,
                              CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), MAX(rtam.dbo.gnr_tbl_72_type.local_col_113), 101) AS max_date
                     FROM     rtam.dbo.GNR_TBL_72_TYPE
                     WHERE    rtam.dbo.GNR_TBL_72_TYPE.CTRL_USER_ID = rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.USER_ID
                     GROUP BY rtam.dbo.GNR_TBL_72_TYPE.CTRL_USER_ID
                     HAVING   rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.LOCAL_USER_START_TIME BETWEEN CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), MIN(rtam.dbo.gnr_tbl_72_type.LOCAL_COL_113), 101) AND CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), MAX(rtam.dbo.gnr_tbl_72_type.LOCAL_COL_113), 101))
GROUP BY rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.USER_ID
ORDER BY rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.USER_ID;
```

Comment: Well what exactly do you expect BETWEEN to mean? It looks like you are converting to a string for some reason - is this to eliminate time? If so, I bet the 13 rows that are missing are from the last day? Please read [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: Same as Huh as Mr Bertrand, Could even start to figure out what made you select the dates in the exist subquery, never mind convert them..

Comment: You need to consider that wrapping a column in a function will prevent SQL server from being able to use indexes and making your query slower. and just like @AaronBertrand said, clarify what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Aaron - Yes, it is eliminating the last day

Comment: If you show sample data and desired results (try on http://sqlfiddle.com), we can probably write a much more efficient and readable query. Otherwise try changing the HAVING clause as below - the query still won't be very efficient, but I think your 13 rows will re-appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
HAVING rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.LOCAL_USER_START_TIME 
  >= CONVERT(DATE, MIN(rtam.dbo.gnr_tbl_72_type.LOCAL_COL_113)) 
AND rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance.LOCAL_USER_START_TIME 
  < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, MAX(rtam.dbo.gnr_tbl_72_type.LOCAL_COL_113))
```

You might also think about using aliases so that you don't have to repeat lengthy and error-prone references like `rtam.dbo.wfm_process_instance` all over your code.

Comment: Hi there! Yes that worked! I will post some sample data from both tables this evening when I get home. Thanks! :)