# Count of records between min date range and other date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the count of records of users who appear between a certain date range, specifically the min(date) for each unique user and that min(date) + 14 days. I've checked this link
[SQL HAVING BETWEEN a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195561/sql-having-between-a-date-range)
but it's not what I'm looking for. Here's an example of what I'm working with and what I've tried to do

```
+----+------------+
| ID | ServiceDt  |
+----+------------+
| 10 | 2017-03-02 |
| 10 | 2017-03-05 |
| 10 | 2017-03-06 |
| 10 | 2017-03-14 |
| 10 | 2017-03-27 |
| 11 | 2017-03-10 |
| 11 | 2017-03-19 |
| 11 | 2017-04-02 |
| 11 | 2017-04-14 |
| 11 | 2017-04-23 |
| .. | ..         |
```

The query is:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ServiceDt) AS date_count 
FROM (
     SELECT ID, ServiceDt
     FROM tbl 
     GROUP BY ID, ServiceDt
     HAVING ServiceDt BETWEEN MIN(ServiceDt) AND DATEADD(day, +14, MIN(ServiceDt))
) AS R1
GROUP BY ID
```

When I do the above query I get the following result.

```
+----+------------+
| ID | date_count |
+----+------------+
| 10 | 5          |
| 11 | 5          |
| .. | ..         |
```

I also tried using `CONVERT(date, ...)`, but I get the same resulting table above. I want the result to be

```
+----+------------+
| ID | date_count |
+----+------------+
| 10 | 4          |
| 11 | 2          |
| .. | ..         |
```

Can someone please guide me on what I can do to get my desired output, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select t.*, min(servicedt) over (partition by id) as min_sd
      from tbl t
     ) t
where servicedt <= dateadd(day, 14, min_sd)
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the first `ServiceDt` for each `id` and use that in your `where` clause.

```
select id, count(*) as date_count
from t
  cross apply (
    select top 1
      i.ServiceDt
    from t i
    where i.Id = t.Id
    order by i.ServiceDt
    ) x
where t.ServiceDt <= dateadd(day,14,x.ServiceDt)
group by id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WXA46698

returns:

```
+----+------------+
| id | date_count |
+----+------------+
| 10 |          4 |
| 11 |          2 |
+----+------------+
```